# UISearchbar using UItextfield in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am working on JSON. My Json data print into the tableview. I want to filtered that data with searchbar. So I put Textfield for using the Searchbar. I use reference from this website

http://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-create-your-own-search-bar-in-Swift-Not-using-UISearchBar/20577/

My Search bar is working but not properly. I want to filter data after I write 3 Words in searchbar.If I write "Ku" then my tableview remain hide. If I write "kus" in searchbar then searchbar started searching and show me filtered data in tableview started from "kus".  my searchbar related code are these

```
struct PatientData:Decodable {
var ID : String
var dt_bod : String
var e_gender : String
var int_glcode : String
var var_email : String
var var_fname : String
var var_phoneno : String
var var_uname : String

init(userdata : [String:Any]) {
    self.ID = userdata["ID"] as! String
    self.dt_bod = userdata["dt_bod"] as! String
    self.e_gender = userdata["e_gender"] as! String
    self.int_glcode = userdata["int_glcode"] as! String
    self.var_email = userdata["var_email"] as! String
    self.var_fname = userdata["var_fname"] as! String
    self.var_phoneno = userdata["var_phoneno"] as! String
    self.var_uname = userdata["var_uname"] as! String

} 

var tabledata = [String]()
var tableFilterData = [String]()
var patientDetails = [PatientData]()

@IBAction func textfieldchanged(_ sender: Any) {
    tableview.isHidden = true
}
```

my textfield change character function

```
public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{

    let searchText  = textField.text! + string
    if searchText.count >= 3 {
        tableview.isHidden = false

        tableFilterData = tabledata.filter({ (result) -> Bool in
            return result.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
        })

        print(tableFilterData)   // I got filtered data here but how to show this data into the tableview
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
    else{
        tableFilterData = []
    }
    return true
}
```

tableview part is

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return patientDetails.count
     }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as UITableViewCell!

    let aa = patientDetails[indexPath.row].var_fname + " , " + patientDetails[indexPath.row].dt_bod + " , " + patientDetails[indexPath.row].var_phoneno

    self.tabledata.append(aa)

        cell.textLabel?.text = aa
        cell.textLabel?.font = searchTextfield.font

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@objc func textFieldActive() {
    tableView.isHidden = tableFilterData.count > 0 ? false : true
}

public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{

    let searchText  = textField.text! + string

    if searchText.count >= 3 {
        tableView.isHidden = false

        tableFilterData = tabledata.filter({ (result) -> Bool in
            return result.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
        })

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else{
        tableFilterData = []
    }

    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableFilterData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = tableFilterData[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = data

    return cell
}
```

Comment: after three word tableview is working properly but it didn't show filter data>

Comment: you need to set filtered data as the tableView dataSource, not the original tableData

Comment: your'e whalecum :)

Comment: sir I edit my code as per your code and also done some changes. I took my json data into the struct and that show in to the tableview. Now I get filtered data but how to show into the tableview is the issue. please help me.

Comment: you are using `patientDetails` as the tableView data source, its very simple, you need to set the data source of your table view to what you want to show, since in this case you are filtering, you should set the tableView data source to a filtered version of your struct

Comment: You said this " cell.textLabel?.text = tableFilterData[indexpath.row]"  Right?

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` will fill your tableView, `cellForRowAt` will present corresponding data, i think you should read the UITableView Documentation from apple to get a better understanding of how it works https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview

Comment: I have to change 'numberOfRowsInSection' and 'cellForRowAt' both. Right? But when I change this with filtered version of my struct tableview show nil. and my print (filtereddata) shows [ ] nil.

Comment: of course it will print nil, you said "I took my json data into the struct", so you need the change your filter method to filter your struct and not `tabledata`

Comment: change filter method?

Comment: right now you have 3 arrays, `tabledata`, `tableFilterData`, `patientDetails`, this is not necessary, you should only have two arrays, the `patientDetails` and a second one which you can name `filteredPatientDetails`. And in the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate you need to filter `patientDetails` instead of `tabledata`.

Comment: "Value of type 'PatientData' has no member 'range'"  error show in to the  'shouldChangeCharactersIn' delegate

Comment: sorry man can't do your work for you, i suggest you either open a new question, or search the web for answers. there are plenty, here's one example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804458/how-to-filter-an-array-of-structs-with-value-of-other-array-in-swift

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift 4 or Swift 5, you can use like bellow..**
Your tableview like bellow
[image]

1. Create a project
2. Create add textfield, tableView connect to viewcontroller
3. add bellow code..

   ```
    class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate{

     @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
     @IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!

     var originalArr = [[String:Any]]();
     var searchArrRes = [[String:Any]]()
     var searching:Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       //Assign delegate  don't forget
       txtName.delegate = self
       tableView.delegate = self
       tableView.dataSource = self

      //my array
     originalArr =   [
       ["name": "abdul", "number": "+8800000001"],
       ["name": "abdin", "number": "+8800000002"],
       ["name": "Enamul", "number": "+8800000003"],
       ["name": "enam", "number": "+8800000004"],
       ["name": "Rafi", "number": "+8800000005"],
       ["name": "Ehaque", "number": "+8800000006"],
       ["name": "ab", "number": "+8800000007"],
       ["name": "Emon", "number": "+8800000008"],
       ["name": "enamu1", "number": "+8800000009"],
       ["name": "rafi", "number": "+88000000010"],
       ["name": "karim", "number": "+88000000011"],
       ["name": "radev", "number": "+88000000012"],
       ["name": "da", "number": "+88000000013"],
       ["name": "aa", "number": "+88000000014"],
       ["name": "rafi", "number": "+88000000010"],
       ["name": "karim", "number": "+88000000011"],
       ["name": "radev", "number": "+88000000012"],
       ["name": "da", "number": "+88000000013"],
       ["name": "aa", "number": "+88000000014"]
      ]

   }


   func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
      textField.resignFirstResponder()
      return true
   }

    public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{
      //input text
      let searchText  = textField.text! + string
     //add matching text to arrya
      searchArrRes = self.originalArr.filter({(($0["name"] as! String).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText))})

     if(searchArrRes.count == 0){
       searching = false
     }else{
       searching = true
    }
     self.tableView.reloadData();

     return true
   }


     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      //check search text & original text
      if( searching == true){
         return searchArrRes.count
      }else{
         return originalArr.count
      }
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     //custom cell Custom_cell
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Custom_cell
     //check search text & original text
      if( searching == true){
       var dict = searchArrRes[indexPath.row]
       cell.label_name.text = dict["name"] as? String
       cell.label_number.text = dict["number"] as? String
     }else{
       var dict = originalArr[indexPath.row]
       cell.label_name.text = dict["name"] as? String
       cell.label_number.text = dict["number"] as? String

    }

     return cell
   }


   }
   ```

You can download full source from GitHub Link: https://github.com/enamul95/TableView_Search

Comment: Reference to your post answer, If possible can I ask one question related to search from tableView?

Answer (score 0):

You can check size of text before filter:

```
public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{

    var searchText  = textField.text! + string

    if string  == "" {
        searchText = (searchText as String).substring(to: searchText.index(before: searchText.endIndex))
    }
    if searchText == "" {
        isSearch = false
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
    else{
        if searchText.count > 2 {
           getSearchArrayContains(searchText)
        }  
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I already tried this but not working. after edit this code when I write first word in searchbar it shows all data not filtered and after I write second word tableview hide and searchbar not working.

Comment: why you not use the `UISearchBar` of NavBar?

Comment: I done this with UISearchBar. But Write now my task is do this things with UITextfield.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:-

```
func getSearchArrayContains(_ text : String) {

    tableFilterData = tableData.filter({$0.lowercased().contains(text)})
    isSearch = true
     tableview.reloadData()
}
```

For should three character use this link[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656501/how-to-do-a-live-uitextfield-count-while-typing-swift):-

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers try to reverse engineer the `UITextField` string by concatenating the change to the previous string. This needed to be done because the delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersIn` is called before the change is made on the `UITextField` string.

These implementations are wrong and do not work when the user scrolls the cursor to the left and continue typing or selects and replaces text (as the answers ignore the `NSRange` delegate variable).

A better implementation is to not use the delegate method at all and instead add a target to the `UITextField`. This works because `UITextField` inherits from `UIControl`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchTextChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
}

@objc func searchTextChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let search = sender.text ?? ""
    filterContentForSearchText(search)
}

func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
    print("Filterin with:", searchText)
    filtered.removeAll()
    filtered = original.filter { thing in
        return "\(thing.value.lowercased())".contains(searchText.lowercased())
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Note: This action can also be created in the storyboard by creating an `@IBAction` and dragging the `Editing Changed` connection from the `UITextField` to the `@IBAction`