# Want to display message in tableview if string in custom search bar doesnt match in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have created custom search bar by using UITextField and have UITableView below it which will display result. How do I display message i.e no record founds when string typed in search bar doesn't match

My storyboard image for search controller:
[image: storyboard image]

My code for search controller file:

```
class SearchPageController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchTxtBar: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchTblView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var helpMessageView: UIView!


    var CatStoreData:[String] = Array()
    var filteredData:[String] = Array()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
        self.helpMessageView.isHidden = true

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        searchTxtBar.delegate = self

        //append data to catstoredata array
        CatStoreData.append("costco.com.au")
        CatStoreData.append("au.kogan.com")
        CatStoreData.append("rebelsport.com.au")
        CatStoreData.append("ebgames.com.au")
        CatStoreData.append("computeralliance.com.au")
        CatStoreData.append("harveynorman-com-au")
        CatStoreData.append("binglee.com.au")
        CatStoreData.append("iwantthatflight.com.au")
        CatStoreData.append("mobileciti.com.au")
        CatStoreData.append("Electronics and Gadgets")
        CatStoreData.append("Baby Care")
        CatStoreData.append("Computers")
        CatStoreData.append("Computers and Laptops")
        CatStoreData.append("Entertainment")
        CatStoreData.append("Eyewear")
        CatStoreData.append("Flights")
        CatStoreData.append("Home & Kitchen")

        for data in CatStoreData {
            filteredData.append(data)
        }

        searchTxtBar.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchRecords(_ :)), for: .editingChanged)

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    @objc func searchRecords(_ textfield: UITextField) {

        self.CatStoreData.removeAll()
        if searchTxtBar.text?.count != 0 {
            for data in filteredData {

                if let dataToSearch = self.searchTxtBar.text {
                    let range = data.lowercased().range(of: dataToSearch, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil)
                    if range != nil {
                        CatStoreData.append(data)
                    }
                }
            }
        }else {
            for data in filteredData {
                CatStoreData.append(data)
            }
        }

        searchTblView.reloadData()
    }

    //MARK: IBActions
    @IBAction func toHomeScreen(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func clearSearchData(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.CatStoreData.removeAll()
        self.searchTxtBar.text = ""
        for data in filteredData {
            CatStoreData.append(data)
        }
        searchTblView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Tableview delegates and datasource methods

```
 extension SearchPageController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return CatStoreData.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "catstoredata")

            if cell == nil {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "catstoredata")
            }

            cell?.selectionStyle = .none
            cell?.textLabel?.text = CatStoreData[indexPath.row]
            return cell!
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Textfield delegates method

```
 extension SearchPageController: UITextFieldDelegate{

        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

            self.searchTxtBar.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Ahmet sina Usten can you help me with my problem?

Comment: Please help me with this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53100452/4711785 . I think you can solve your problem with it

Comment: Not getting it. Can u send me simple demo from my code